# Find file in external jar not in my classpath

Tags: java, scala

I´m running some test and I need to get the path of a file that it´s in a jar lib that I have in my project as dependency.

This jar is not part of the classpath that I run.

If I try something like

```
val path =  getClass.getResource("h2-1.3.161.jar").getPath
```

in my test it does not work.

Any idea how to find a file inside a jar without be this jar part of your classpath?

Regards.

Using the solution of astrograph I manage to get this route

```
java -cp //file:/D:/Users/nb38tv/workspace/f2e-core/f2e-mock/f2e-test-framework/target/f2e-test-framework-1.8.3-SNAPSHOT.jar!/h2/sakila-h2-master/h2-1.3.161.jar -ifExists -tcp -web -tcpAllowOthers
```

But java complain since cannot find the jar.

If I remove the `!` from the path I receive this error

```
Unrecognized option: -ifExists
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Any idea?

Regards

Comment: Java has a JAR-related API to programmatically open and edit JARs. [Check here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/apiindex.html)

Comment: `jar` files are simple `zip` archive. You can find dock [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html)

Comment: The [OSGI](http://www.osgi.org/) framework is designed to do this. There are ways to do this without a framework but I wouldn't recommend it. Loading and executing a remote Jar can be a security problem if you don't do it right.

Comment: @Mark OSGI is designed to do that; however, OSGI is also designed to do a lot more.  If I want a soda, I typically prefer not to buy the whole restaurant. :)  Not mentioning the versioning, dynamic discovery, ability to unload classes, and the command layer of OSGI is not cool.  Finally, you trade off library structure with framework structure, which is great if you are working within the framework, but otherwise is a conversion cost.

Comment: @Mark I manage to get the jar path but I cannot make it work. Can you see my edited question again please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the file a .class file?
Can you open the file in your test?
Can you instantiate a class from that jar file?

To get to the location of a class you can use the following method:
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());

Comment: I manage to get the jar path but still not working. Can you take a look to my question again? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "find" the file.

If you mean "detect if the class file exists", then you can use the Java Zip file handling routines.  Inside your code, open the Jar file as a Zip file.

If you mean "use the class file" within your program, and for some reason you cannot put it on your class file (perhaps it doesn't exist in that location at startup time) then you need to use an additional class loader which will look for the file after the file is present.  To do this, I recommend you reuse at URLClassLoader, even if your file is local to the disk, just use a `file:///` URL.

Comment: I manage to get the jar path but I cannot make it work. Can you see my edited question again please

Comment: @paul It looks like you have a Jar file embedded in a Jar file.  Java doesn't handle such things, Jar files contain classes, but not other Jar files.  I suggest you deploy the embedded Jar file separately.

Comment: The idea was to avoid people to have to bring that jar, just bring the first level one and  then this one bring the other one.

Comment: @paul It is not a bad idea, but Java doesn't ship with class loaders that load Jars from Jars, and the Jar specification doesn't have any clause within it that says Jar files contain other Jar files.  Sure, you can stick them in, because the Jar file is really a Zip file (with a few special requirements) but if you use them outside of the specification, it is up to you to figure out how to make it work (you'll need a very custom classloader).

Comment: it´s a shame that such an important feature it´s not possible. I will try to find a more pragmatic solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @paul Its not such an important feature.  If it was very important, Java would not have been widely accepted without it.   Once you open up "loading Jar files from within Jar files" you then open up "loading Jar files from within Jar files from within Jar files".  No language that I know of loads libraries embedded into other libraries.  Jar files are the equivalent of Libraries, but because people know the library is implemented like a zip file, they are not blocked from putting libraries in libraries.